# How can I wait a function to finish in Java?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm developing an Android app in Java that needs to load some data from a remote database. For that I have a function called `getCards()` that reads the DB and loads some information into `SharedPreferences`. In my main function I want to read those infromation written in the `SharedPreferences`and write them on a `TextView`. The thing is that when I try to get those information from `SharedPreferences`they seem to be null because the thread does not wait for "getCards()" to finish. If i go into another activity and then come back in the main activity, the data will be put, but when I first start the activity the read from `SharedPreferences`is too fast. Any suggestions? I've tried with wait(100) surrounded by try/catch, but the wapp would crash.

This is the code from the main activity.

```
        getCards();
       
        ccnr = pref.getString("ccnumber",null);
        ccfn = pref.getString("fullname",null);
        if(ccfn == null || ccnr ==null){
            tvccnumber.setText("No card was added!");
            tvccfullname.setText("No card was added!");

        }else{
            tvccnumber.setText(ccnr);
            tvccfullname.setText(ccfn);
        }
```

This is the part of `getCards()` that loads the information in `SharedPreferences`.

```
public void getCards(){
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Constants.GETC_URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        if(!response.contains("Error!")){
                            JSONArray jsonArray;
                            JSONObject jsonObject;
                            String ccnumber;
                            String fullname;
                            String ccsignature;
                            try {
                                jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
                                jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
                                ccnumber = jsonObject.getString("ccNumber");
                                ccsignature = jsonObject.getString("ccSign");
                                fullname = jsonObject.getString("fullName");
                                editor.putString("ccnumber",ccnumber);
                                editor.putString("ccsignature",ccsignature);
                                editor.putString("fullname",fullname);
                                editor.commit();
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }else{
                            Toast.makeText(FinalUserSpace.this, response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
```

Comment: use a if else statement, like say (this is pseudo code) 
 if (sharedprefrences = null) { do something
}
else{
getCards
}

the if statement should make it only load if shared prefrences has something loaded

Comment: once the data comes then send data to shared pref and then load into textview

Comment: How do I know the data is loaded? I`ve tried to make the function getCards() boolean and return true when it finishes, and then check for the return in the main function, but it still returns before it writes in the sharedpreferences.

Comment: Put your completion code inside the completion callback?

Answer (score 0):

You may use a java object to lock until the fonction return.

```
private Object lock = new Object();
```

```
public void getcards(){
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Constants.GETC_URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        if(!response.contains("Error!")){
                            JSONArray jsonArray;
                            JSONObject jsonObject;
                            String ccnumber;
                            String fullname;
                            String ccsignature;
                            try {
                                jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
                                jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
                                ccnumber = jsonObject.getString("ccNumber");
                                ccsignature = jsonObject.getString("ccSign");
                                fullname = jsonObject.getString("fullName");
                                editor.putString("ccnumber",ccnumber);
                                editor.putString("ccsignature",ccsignature);
                                editor.putString("fullname",fullname);
                                editor.commit();
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }else{
                            Toast.makeText(FinalUserSpace.this, response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                        lock.notifyAll();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
```

```
getcards();
       
lock.wait();

ccnr = pref.getString("ccnumber",null);
ccfn = pref.getString("fullname",null);
if(ccfn == null || ccnr ==null){
    tvccnumber.setText("No card was added!");
    tvccfullname.setText("No card was added!");
}else{
    tvccnumber.setText(ccnr);
    tvccfullname.setText(ccfn);
}
```